# How to calculate relative importance of predictors in neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, statistics

I have to model a neural network with two inputs and one output. I have to use single hidden layer and single node in hidden layer. The question says 'For neural network model trained, compute the relative
importance (RI) of the two predictors. You are free to use any metric to quantify the importance
of predictors'. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, not sure why you would ever have a single-node hidden layer in practice. So here is a hint, how would you do this if the same problem had to be done for linear regression?

Comment: Thanks Ananda, This is a  homework question I am stuck with. I do not know how to calculate the relative importance. Kindly help if possible.

Comment: Straight up giving an answer to a homework problem is frowned upon on StackOverflow. So think about how you would you do this for linear regression (that's even googleable if you don't know). Your case is not all that different from linear regression (try to think why)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, the general sense that I get from the guidelines is to try to guide the original poster towards an answer rather than straight up giving it. Which is what I think I did.

Comment: Apologies then, I misunderstood your statement. Deleting and re-posting my  comment.

Comment: @Vishal - Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Please update your question to be in line with the expectation that the SO community has w.r.t homework questions. It is advisable that you do some amount of prior research yourself on the topic as well. `Not putting any effort towards your question yourself and directly asking is frowned upon, not homework questions in general.`

Comment: Hi everyone, I read this and now understand the guidelines. I have done some search and found that relative importance of predictors can be found using connection weights of different features. Please verify if I am correct. Will not it be good to use partial correlation between predicted (test) values and inputs to find relative importance? Kindly help.

Comment: You are on the right track with thinking about the weights of the network. However, this strategy of looking at weights doesn't work in general for neural nets. But it does make sense in your case (hint: the fact that the hidden layer is a single node is important here). As to your question about looking at partial correlation, you can use that to find the relative importance between two variables, yes. But that's not what the question is asking. The question is *not*, what feature is more important; it's what feature does your NN *think* is more important.

Comment: thanks Ananda. This solves my doubt.